# How do you remove visual studio's navigation bar in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to remove visual studio's navigation bar in VB.net, I know how to remove it in c# but unfortunately it has no effect in VB.net.

would appreciate any help.

[image]

i'm trying to remove the bar with DBLoggingProvider and (Declarations)

Comment: If you can't do it the same way as in C#, it can't be done.

Comment: are there any addons that would let me do it?